# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20b9' in position 5: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

Here is my code, I am scraping the data of 99acres website and storing it in a csv file but when i am doing so it gives me a error message of 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20b9'...Please Tell me how it will be resolved...

```
import io
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://www.99acres.com/search/property/buy/residential-all/hyderabad?search_type=QS&search_location=HP&lstAcn=HP_R&lstAcnId=0&src=CLUSTER&preference=S&selected_tab=1&city=269&res_com=R&property_type=R&isvoicesearch=N&keyword_suggest=hyderabad%3B&fullSelectedSuggestions=hyderabad&strEntityMap=W3sidHlwZSI6ImNpdHkifSx7IjEiOlsiaHlkZXJhYmFkIiwiQ0lUWV8yNjksIFBSRUZFUkVOQ0VfUywgUkVTQ09NX1IiXX1d&texttypedtillsuggestion=hyder&refine_results=Y&Refine_Localities=Refine%20Localities&action=%2Fdo%2Fquicksearch%2Fsearch&suggestion=CITY_269%2C%20PREFERENCE_S%2C%20RESCOM_R&searchform=1&price_min=null&price_max=null')

html = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

list=[]

dealer = soup.findAll('div',{'class': 'srpWrap'})


for item in dealer:
    try:
        p = item.contents[1].find_all("div",{"class":"_srpttl srpttl fwn wdthFix480 lf"})[0].text
    except:
        p=''
    try:
          d = item.contents[1].find_all("div",{"class":"lf f13 hm10 mb5"})[0].text
    except:
          d=''
    li=[p,d]
    list.append(li)

with io.open('project.csv','w',encoding="utf-8") as file:
    writer= csv.writer(file)
    for row in list:
        writer.writerows(row)
file.close()
```

Comment: yes, that is your code. What are you trying to tell us about it?

Comment: When i running this code it gives me a error which i am posting below...And i am unable to unbug it so i need ur help to get out of this.

""Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Divyam\Desktop\Python\project.py", line 27, in <module>
    writer.writerow(row)
  File "C:\Users\Divyam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20b9' in position 5: character maps to <undefined>""

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error message, don't post it in comments where it can't be properly formatted and will be harder to find.

Answer (score 0):

Use:  **`.encode(encoding = 'UTF-8')`**

Comment: yup it removes the error but still i am not getting the file

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please describe why your solution works. That may seem obvious, but it isn't: Encoding is a touchy subject that many people do not understand well.